# How to set value of icefaces inputTextarea control

Tags: jsf, icefaces-1.8

I'm using Icefaces 1.8.2 and an `ice:inputTextarea` control, and I can't figure why the value is not getting set here:

.jsp

```
<ice:inputTextarea binding="#{easp$RecordSearch.repairRemark}" id="repairRemark"
  partialSubmit="true" style="height:40px; width:100%;" />
```

.java

```
//bean
private HtmlInputTextarea repairRemark = new HtmlInputTextarea();
public HtmlInputTextarea getRepairRemark() {
    return repairRemark;
}
public void setRepairRemark(HtmlInputTextarea hit) {
    this.repairRemark = hit;
}

....
public String button3_action() {
    ...

    //code that sets value
    String myVal = "new value";
    this.repairRemark.setValue(myVal);

    ...
    return null;
}
```

The code that sets the value is part of a button click event that I know is getting fired because I'm setting several other Icefaces controls, and all the other setters are working except this one. I just noticed that it actually appears to set the text very briefly, but disappears instantly. I checked all the code on that page, and I'm almost certain there is no other setter overwriting it. Does anyone know what is going here?

**Update:**
It does not seem to be a "phase" related issue, as this event is being processed in the `INVOKE_APPLICATION` phase. Also to note, I'm experiencing the same issue with the jsf `h:inputTextarea`

Comment: Any reason you are using `binding` here and create the component manually instead of just `value`?

Comment: @mrembisz No reason I'm aware of. I'm actually maintaining this code, it was not originally written by me. The only code I wrote is the `button3_action()` event.

Comment: @mrembisz I do notice on [this page](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v1_8_0/tld/ice/inputTextarea.html), under *value*, that it says "All UIInput derived UIComponents, that are placed within a UIData container, such as a dataTable or panelSeries, should have their **value** attribute bound to a bean property via a ValueBinding/ValueExpression, since otherwise the UIData container will not keep their successfully validated state, which can cause the component to fail to function properly." And it is within a panel series.

Comment: I tried changing `binding` to `value`, and now I'm just seeing `com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.HtmlInputTextarea@a5b9dd` in the textbox

Comment: In your case `value` should indicate a string property to be edited by this component. `Binding` indicates an entire component. So you would have to change repairMark to String in bean and use `this.repairMark = myVal`.

Comment: @mrembisz Ah, got ya. Thanks for your response. I just tried that and I am getting the same results. The text appears in the `Textarea` for a split second, and then disappears :(

Comment: I removed the `binding` attribute, and used a different bean name `value="#{....repairRemarkVal}"`, so I'm pretty sure it is not being overwritten by some code.

Comment: I even made a 2nd similar `inputTextarea` control right next to it, and set the same value to it and the same thing happened to both `Textarea`s >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause and solution. The cause was the `ice:commandButton`s that were triggering this click event were in a column in a `ice:dataTable`. The `ice:dataTable` had an `ice:rowSelector` that seemed like it was causing an additional server request when a button was clicked. When I removed the `ice:rowSelector`, the problem went away.

The solution was to add either `toggleOnClick="false"` or `toggleOnInput="false"` to the `ice:rowSelector`. I added both, just in case.

http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v1_8_2/tld/ice/rowSelector.html

Hope this helps anyone else that runs into this issue.